# What is a signature or token in a login system and how does it work?

Tags: php, authentication

I have seen a few php login systems that use a signature mechanism to validate subsequent requests after the user has logged in. For example while logging in something like the following is stored in a session variable. And then with every page request of the application, this signature is recreated and matched with the signature in the session variable.

```
$_SESSION["signature"] = sha1($salt . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
```

My questions about this are:

1. Why do we use a signature or token? How does it protect in general?
2. What is a salt and why use it in a signature. Aren't IP address and user-agent enough?
3. Also, why use a hash function when the signature is stored as a session variable on the server anyway?

Comment: 1. [Against Cross-site Forgery Request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). 2. Because it's unique enough. No, they aren't enough. Those can be spoofed. 3. Because it's easy to make and as I said unique enough for the life of the session.

Comment: Do you mean something like a 'remember me' cookie? [Implementing Secure User Authentication in PHP Applications with Long-Term Persistence](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence#title.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These kind of tokens are used to guard against [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). It is officially known as the "Synchronizer token pattern". By checking if this token is valid, you can prevent attackers from fooling other users into performing certain actions (Example: Fooling another user into deleting a record by getting them to submit a POST request to a given URL. Fooling a user into logging out by getting them to click on the logout URL).

The salt is used because it makes the token more difficult to spoof (not only does the attacker need to spoof the IP address and the user agent, they also need to figure out what the salt it).

Comment: The comments with my question are also very useful.